# Leaflet, defining a specific region for a canvas to draw upon

Tags: leaflet

Using leaflet, you can draw on a given map by adding a Canvas layer.  Some instructions are given here, http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#tilelayer-canvas

```
var canvasTiles = new L.TileLayer.Canvas();

canvasTiles.drawTile = function(canvas, tilePoint, zoom) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // draw something on the tile canvas
}
```

However, I'd like to to draw at a specific lat-long location on the map, can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at defining a custom layer: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#ilayer

Answer (score 0):

So canvas layer might be a bit of overkill to you it might make sense to look at [marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) or [circle marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker) if you do need to use a canvas layer I believe you have to transform the latlng into the layer coordinates system, and then use the canvas layer functions to map it.